# How to setup the Cascade Delete?

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables:

```
Clinic
 - Id
 - ...

ClinicRequest
 - Id
 - ClinicId
 - ContactDataId
 - ...

ContactData
 - Id
 - ...
```

"Clinic.Id" is one-to-many "ClinicRequest.ClinicId", and "ClinicRequest.ContactDataId" is one-to-one "ContactData.Id". (Also, "ContactData" has same one-to-one relation with another tables and this relation will later need cascaded delete too)

Basically, I would like to achieve cascade delete on "Clinic" object and, subsequently, on "ClinicRequest" object.

I tried establishing this using ForeignKey ON CASCADE DELETE, but it seems I can only do it backwards, which is (Primary key table-ContactData-Id)(Foreign key table-ClinicRequest-ContactDataId), and that is not what I need. I can do this with Triggers, but I've read it is a bad practice. Also, I definitely don't want this logic to be present in my application. 
Can anyone please give me any directions how to deal with this?

Comment: Create a FK from ClinicRequest TO Clinic and on this set cascade

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, but I don't know how to setup cascade FK for ClinicRequest and ContactData relation. After all, I ended up writing a trigger.